# implementing function search in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to implement a search function in Laravel 5 but I'm not getting any results with my queries.
I keep getting this error

"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

This is `search()` function in `frequencesController`

```
public function search(){
    $results = frequences::where(function($q) use ($request) {
        $q->orWhere('time_db', 'like', 'time');
    })->get();
}
```

this is route:

```
Route::post('search', ['as' => 'search', 'frequences' => 'frequencesController@search']);
```

and page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>search</title>
    </head>


    <body>
         <form action="App\Http\Controllers\frequencesController@search" method="post">
             <p>time</p>   
             <input type="time" name="search " value="time"/>
             <input type="submit" value="search"> 
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

what's the problem? please

Comment: form action="App\Http\Controllers\frequencesController@search" should instead be a URL like "/search" or "yourdomain/search" etc

Comment: i keep getting this : The requested URL /search was not found on this server.
how can I fix it ?

Comment: Try to replace frequences on your route to 'uses' instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $search=$request->get('search')
    $results = frequences::where(function($q) use ($search) {
        $q->orWhere('time_db', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    })->get();
}
```

in form

```
<form action="{{url('/search')}}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
             <p>time</p>   
             <input type="time" name="search" value="time">
             <input type="submit" value="search"> 
         </form>
```